# Git Merge and Missing changes

Tags: git, github, git-merge

I'm a bit new to **GitHub**. Sorry in advance if this is a noob question.
I have 2 branches, `Dev` and `Master`. I worked on `Dev`. When I wanted to merge with `Master`, I did the following:

```
$ git checkout master
$ git pull origin master
$ git merge dev
```

then i had a few conflicts. I fixed the conflicts using Sourcetree.

Then when I committed the new changes, using:

```
$ git commit -m "Dev merged in Master"
```

the files that were not conflicted were showing in `Master` branch but the files that had conflict weren't showing any changes.

They were on `Dev` but not on `Master`.

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Did you merge resolved conflict changes with marster ?

Comment: I didn't merge after resolving conflict. i read one place that it would cause a big issue..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not have enough reputation to add a comment, so apologies for writing this as an answer.

as @Jérémy Giuseppi mentions, you must always add files after any modifications if you wish to include them in your commit. When you resolved the conflict, you made modifications to files B but use of `git commit -m 'message'` did not include those updates.

To avoid this in the future, I suggest using `git commit -a -m 'message'`, where the `-a` flag tells git to add all modified files since last commit to the new commit message.

Checkout [How to resolve merge conflicts in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/161813/how-to-resolve-merge-conflicts-in-git?rq=1) to see a workflow of resolving conflicts in git

Comment: Thank you for the info.. ned time will follow it :)

Answer (score 3):

Did you mark your files as resolved ?

In CLI, when the conflicts are solved : `git add yourFile` to stage this file before you end the merge.